# TCPDF page count of html content

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate a PDF document from dynamic html content which is stored as $html string. I then use the following code to make the PDF:

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

if I add the following line before outputting the file

```
    $totalPageCount = $pdf->getNumPages();
```

It can give me the total page count in that PDF document. However, before then outputting it using the code below:

```
    $pdf->Output('info.pdf', 'I');
```

Is there a way I can add some more html content if my page number meets the following condition:

```
if (($totalPageCount>=1) && ($totalPageCount % 2 != 0)) {
```

Comment: Didn't understood this part "However, before then outputting it using the code below:", can you please rephrase it?

Comment: What if your condition is met, but when adding more content it's no longer met and you have to remove that content, but then your condition is met again [... x infinite times]

Comment: @Ofir Baruch What i meant is before generating the pdf by using pdf->Output is there a way I can get the page count and store it as $totalPagecount variable and then use the condition.

Comment: @Justinas the condition needs to be checked only once after putting $html into the pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No replies, but it seems that the instance of $pdf lets you add more content using writeHTML. so what i've done is this:

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$totalPageCount = $pdf->getNumPages();
if (($totalPageCount>=1) && ($totalPageCount % 2 != 0)) {
    $pdf->writeHTML('<div><tcpdf method="AddPage" /></div>This page is intentionally blank.', true, false, true, false, '');
}
$pdf->Output('info.pdf', 'I');
```